# Testing if jquery.dimensions.js is installed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

hello can I get some tips on how i can test if I have implemented jquery.dimensions correctly?

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions

sort of like when u test for jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

I am trying to implement a floating menu bar on a site. suspect that I have not installed dimensions correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if a plugin is loaded with:

```
if(jQuery().somePluginName) {
   // plugin is loaded
 }
```

Comment: if(jQuery().dimensions){
        alert('dimensions');
    }

Comment: hmm failed is there google ajax for dimensions plug in?

will rep u after 10 mins limit

Comment: As far as I know Google doesn't host that plugin unfortunately. Check your HTML source to make sure the dimensions script is properly linked, and also check that it is loaded after the jquery core.